# delete past save entries of core data in swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a problem where i cannot completely delete data stored in core data entities. i am storing the username and password in a login system.

i am aware of using the .deleteObject() method but to be honest im not sure if this is actually working as i do a print statement to check in console what is stored and it appears to have not been deleted

here is my code:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    //add user to core data

    let user = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    do{

    try context.save()

    }catch{

    print("there was an error saving to core data")

    }

    do{

        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

        if results.count > 0{
            for item in results as! [NSManagedObject]{

                let username = item.valueForKey("username")
                let password = item.valueForKey("password")

                context.deleteObject(item)

                print("aawawaw \(username), \(password)")

            }

        }

    }catch{

        print("there was an error")

    }
```

[image: this is what i get in print statement]

Comment: if you store the properties of `item` in constants, then delete `item`, the constants will still have their values. This is in no way in indication of a successful deletion.

Comment: im aware of that  however if you look at my image nothing gets removed from past entries

Comment: Just saying that a successful test will help you find the cause of the problem faster. Anyway, save the context after deletion.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the values that are stored in the let constants . 
Try to implement  in for loop

```
            context.deleteObject(item)
            let username = item.valueForKey("username")
            let password = item.valueForKey("password")
            print("aawawaw \(username), \(password)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not really delete the objects from CD.

You should:

1. delete the object.
2. store the context
3. then perform a new fetch on the entity
4. print all instances of the entity

What you actually do is different:

1. store the context (with which changes whatever, but noting related to your question)
2. fetch the entity
3. delete object from the CD context
4. print the object that is still around although detached from CD.
5. as far as t. You are doing: 
   we can see, you don't save anything and threfore don't save the deleted state.